# Sending many parrallel WebRequests

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, webrequest

I'm trying to simulate many concurrent users (>2000) to test a web service. Every user performs actions at a specific pre-defined time, for example:

- User A: 09:10:02, 09:10:03, 09:10:08
- User B: 09:10:03, 09:10:05, 09:10:07
- User C: 09:10:03, 09:10:09, 09:10:15, 09:10:20

I now want to send web request in real time at each of those times. I can tolerate a delay of at most ~2 seconds. What I was already trying without success:

a) Aggregate all times in a single list, sort it by time then iterate it:

```
foreach (DateTime sendTime in times) {
    while (DateTime.now < sendTime)
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    SendRequest();
}
```

b) Create a thread for each user, with each thread checking for the same condition as above but a longer sleep time

Both approaches kind of work, but the delay between the time that the request was supposed to be sent and the time that it has actually been sent is way too high. Is there any way to send the requests with higher precision?

Edit: The suggests approaches work really well. However, the delay is still extremely high for many requests. Apparantly, the reason for this is my SendRequest() method:

```
private static async Task SendRequest()
{
    // Log time difference
    string url = "http://www.request.url/newaction";
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
 }
```

Note that my web service does not return any response, maybe this is the reason for the slow down? Can I send the request without waiting for the response?

Comment: and your question?

Comment: I have added a more specific question

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a timer object to trigger the requests:

```
// In Form_Load or another init method
Timer tRequest = new Timer();
tRequest.Interval = 500;
tRequest.Tick += TRequest_Tick;

private void TRequest_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var sendTimes = times.Where(t => t.AddMilliseconds(-500) < DateTime.Now && t.AddMilliseconds(500) > DateTime.Now);

     foreach(DateTime sendTime in sendTimes)
     {
         SendRequest();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this with multiple thread? Threading requires slow sleep/wake context switching. You could just do this all with timers/async calls.

```
List<DateTime> scheduledTimes = ...;
List<Task> requests = scheduledTimes
                         .Select(t => t - DateTime.Now)
                         .Select(async delay => 
                         {
                             await Task.Delay(delay);
                             SendRequest();
                         })
                         .ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(requests);
```

The above code will in one thread schedule all the requests onto the `SynchronizationContext` and run them.

Simples.

Comment: Thank you, this works really well. However, the delay is still pretty high with many requests because of my SendRequest() method. I edited my post for more information.

Comment: @aseipel I think actually the reason is because you are hitting connectionManager limits. It is also possible that you are hitting the limits of your http server (IIS on non-server Windows is intentionally hobbled with a connection limit as well).

Comment: How can I check if this is the case? I already increased the maxconnection attribute in my App.config, the IIS connection limit of my service and the application pool queueLength.

Comment: @aseipel what version of Windows are you running on the IIS on? http://jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm You can change these limits by uninstalling Windows and installing a server version of Windows.

Comment: I was running both the service and my test application on Windows 7. However, I have now deployed both programs on two different servers with Windows Server 2016. In the request, I'm sending two timestamps: a) the time at which the request was supposed to be sent (as determinded in the scheduledTimes list) as well as the time at which the request was actually sent. It turns out that the application that sends the requests is too slow as the difference between actually sent/received is near zero, while the difference between supposed to be sent/received keeps going up